# Proper ajax script, which gets list of object from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like ajax to get list of the countryResponses, get names and append it into `<select>` as options.
there is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <select id = "countrySelect" >
            <option disabled>Countries</option>
        </select>
        <script>     
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:8080/public/getAllCountries",
                type:"GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType:"application/json",
                success: function(countriesList){
                    for(var i = 0; i<countries.length; i++){
                        var countryName = countriesList[i].name;
                        $("#countrySelect").append('<option value = "' + countryName + '">' + countryName + '</option>' ); 
                    } 
                },
                error:function(error){
                    alert("error");
                }
            });    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is the proof, that get method works: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HizMa.png).

Comment: what is your point?

Comment: `countryName ` is an object not a string and there is no `$("#myTable")` in the html shown

Comment: Please note you never specified an actual problem within this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable's name is `countriesList` and you referenced an undefined variable `contries` in the `for` loop.

To get the name of each record you should use `var countryName = countriesList[i].name` instead of `var countryName = countriesList[i]`.

The `ID` of the `select` tag is 'countrySelect' not 'myTable'.

Here's an the corrected script, it should work for you:

```
<script>     
    $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:8080/public/getAllCountries",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(countriesList){
                for(var i = 0; i<countriesList.length; i++){
                    var countryName = countriesList[i].name;
                    $("#countrySelect").append('<option value = "' + countryName + '">' + countryName + '</option>' ); 
                } 
            },
            error:function(error){
                alert("error");
            }
        });    
</script>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: thank you for your response. It helped me to make it work the way I wanted. The main goal was to check if all code is ok. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

There is final working code. Hopefully it helps someone!

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
   <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>  


   <select id = "countrySelect" >
       <option disabled>Countries</option>
   </select>

<script>     
    $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:8080/public/getAllCountries",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:"application/json",
            success: function(countryList){
                for(var i = 0; i<countryList.length; i++){
                    var countryName = countryList[i].name;
                    $("#countrySelect").append('<option value = "' + countryName + '">' + countryName + '</option>' ); 
                } 
            },
            error:function(error){
                alert("error");
            }
        });    
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```